# C#: finding the sum in a for loop

Tags: c#

the question asks:

Write a program that reads from the screen two integer numbers min and max and outputs the sum of all squares of integers between min(including) and max(not including). If min is bigger than max, the program should output       "min should be smaller than max!". Example:

```
>4
>9
190 (= 4² + 5² + 6² + 7² + 8²)

>14
>3
min should be smaller than max!
```

my code:

```
using System;

namespace ForLoops
{
    class SumOfSquares
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


        int sum = 0;
        int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = min; i < max; i = i++)
        {
             sum = i * i; 



            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);

        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting 68 when i should get 190.

Comment: `sum += i * i;` And also replace `i = i++` with `i++`

Comment: You can't get 68, you should be getting 64.

Comment: with `i = i++` this should be an infinite loop

Comment: This problem does not need a loop: `max--;res=(2*max*max*max+3*max*max+max-2*min*min*min-3*min*min-min)/6`

Comment: why use the +=? i am a beginner just learning with a online corse for free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two flaws in your code:

1. The [*post-increment operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator) `i++` increments `i`, but **returns the previous value**. So by `i = i++` you never increase `i` because you always reassign the value as it was before the increment. This leads to an infinite loop.
2. You didn't sum up the products, but only assigned individual productes with `sum = i * i;`. You need to add them with `sum += i*i;`.

So your final loop could look like that:

```
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
      sum += i * i;
```

Comment: it worked, why did you use the plus or equal operation?

Comment: @MarilynLacey it's not "plus or euqal", it's a short version for `sum = sum + (i * i);`

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is you make it to For Loop statement so you can have the 2 examples. Answers at the same time.

```
        int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if(min > max)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("min should be smaller than max!");
        }
        else
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = min; i < max; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + i*i;
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Linq* is altertative to get rid of explicit loops (and let .net do the work for you):

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  int min = 4;
  int max = 9;

  int sum = Enumerable
    .Range(min, max - min) // from min to max (not included)
    .Sum(x => x * x);      // sum up squares
```